# D3.js multiple area chart not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am following this [tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/29/multiple-area-charts-with-d3-js/) for creating multiple area charts with D3.js and I want to customize it to my data.
His data is:

```
Year, Variable1, Variable2, etc
```

My data is

```
YYYYMMDD, variable1, variable2, etc
```

I changed this part of the code to convert the date column to a Date object:

```
function createChart(data){
                            var countries = [];
                            var charts = [];
                            var maxDataPoint = 0;

                            /* Loop through first row and get each country 
                                and push it into an array to use later */
                            for (var prop in data[0]) {
                                if (data[0].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                                    if (prop != 'Day') {
                                        countries.push(prop);
                                    }
                                }
                            };

                            var countriesCount = countries.length;
                            var startYear = (data[0].Day).substr(0,4);
                            var endYear = (data[data.length - 1].Day).substr(0,4);
                            var chartHeight = height * (1 / countriesCount);

                            /* Let's make sure these are all numbers, 
                            we don't want javaScript thinking it's text 

                            Let's also figure out the maximum data point
                            We'll use this later to set the Y-Axis scale
                            */
                            data.forEach(function(d) {
                                for (var prop in d) {
                                    if (d.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                                        d[prop] = parseFloat(d[prop]);

                                        if (d[prop] > maxDataPoint) {
                                            maxDataPoint = d[prop];
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                // D3 needs a date object, let's convert it just one time
                                var y = (d.Day).substr(0,4),
                                        m = (d.Day).substr(4,2) - 1,
                                        d = (d.Day).substr(6,2);
                                    d.Day = new Date(y,m,d);

                            });
```

This is a sample of my data and there is around 400 rows

```
Day NYTimes Guardian    The Peninsula   Gulf Times
20101201    1   8   2   0
20101203    3   9   2   0
20101205    6   10  4   1
20101207    2   9   5   1
20101209    1   3   7   0
20101211    12  8   6   0
20101213    3   4   3   0
```

No graph is shown, I just get a blank page  and no errors on the console, take a look [here](http://www.qatar.cmu.edu/~jmoussa/Media/MultipleAreaChartsD3/). What is wrong?

Comment: I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Object 20101201 has no method 'substr'" when loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the code, the Day value is getting converted from a string ("20101201") to an integer (20101201). You are then getting a no method substr error when trying use .substr() on a integer.

Try converting the var y to a string using .toString() by replacing line:

```
var y = (d.Day).substr(0,4)
```

With

```
var y = (d.Day).toString().substr(0,4)
```

Or consider using the [d3's built in time parsing functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-parse)